# How to fill state/region/subregion selections when page is opened in edit mode?

Tags: laravel-livewire

In  Laravel 8/livewire 2/aplinejs I need to fill state/region/subregion, which are tables in db
and I select subregion from priorly selected regions and select regions from priorly selected, like

```
public function updatedSelectedState($state_id)
{
    $this->regionsSelectionArray       = Region::getRegionsSelectionArray($state_id, 'A');
    $this->detailsForm['state_id']     = $state_id;
}

public function updatedSelectedRegion($region_id)
{
    $this->subregionsSelectionArray    = Subregion::getSubregionsSelectionByRegionIdArray($region_id);
    $this->selectedSubregion           = null;
}
```

it works ok for data inserting , but when I open editor in “edit” mode and I neeed to fill initvalue I
failed how do it. I remember when I made similar tasks with jquery I have common bool var which I set to true
when jquery was inited. And in onChange event I checked this var .
But how can I do it in livewire ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the docs, "*updated Runs after any update to the Livewire component's data (Using wire:model, not directly inside PHP)*". Does that clarify? Hard to say more explicit without seeing the bigger picture. The accepted answer is however not a good solution, as the lifecycle-hooks should never be called manually!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the below functions in your edit method
Example:

```
public function updatedSelectedState($state_id)
{
$this->changeSelectedState($state_id);
}

public function updatedSelectedRegion($region_id)
{
$this->changeSelectedRegion($region_id);
}

public function changeSelectedState($state_id){
$this->regionsSelectionArray = Region::getRegionsSelectionArray($state_id, 'A');
$this->detailsForm['state_id'] = $state_id;
}

public function changeSelectedRegion($region_id)
{
$this->subregionsSelectionArray = Subregion::getSubregionsSelectionByRegionIdArray($region_id);
$this->selectedSubregion = null;
}

public function edit(){
// $state_id = provide your state id here
// $region_id = provide your region id here

$this->changeSelectedState($state_id);
$this->changeSelectedRegion($region_id);
}
```

Comment: That's a very bad idea. These are lifecycle-hooks in Livewire, and they should not be called manually!

Comment: Can you provide better decision ?

Comment: @Qirel please check the updated answer. I think this is more suitable. we didn't want to call the lifecycle-hooks directly.

Comment: @PetroGromovo, Please check it now